# Is there any evidence that the 'tea' in the Imperial Radch books is actually tea?

Tags: imperial-radch

Tea is an element of (at least) Radch, Orsian and Nilter culture. However, according to Breq, the different cultures mean different things when they say 'tea'. Based on Breq's description of a thick, chalky liquid, it doesn't seem like Orsian tea is the tea we're familiar with. Is there any evidence that Radch tea is actually tea, *Camellia sinensis*?

Comment: I just finished re-reading the series a couple of days ago, and don't remember anything that indicates it's tea as we know it.  It's prepared with a strainer, and low-quality tea is the "sweepings from the floor", can be made into 'bricks' - all of which are true about real -life tea.

Comment: I'd say no. If I recall correctly (though my memory might be mistaken), there is no reference at all to Earth or any recognizable Earth animals (like horses) or plants (like roses); hence, there is no way to say that 'tea' is Camellia sinensis. Also, 'tea' is often used as a general term for herbal infusions, e.g. camomile tea.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Actually Earth was once mentioned and their tea is diuretic quite like ours.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - There's no way ***if we only use the books as a reference.***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question was addressed in [a blog post on Ann Leckie's own website](https://annleckie.com/2014/09/22/tea-2/). In short, the 'tea' in the novels is indeed *[Camellia sinensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sinensis)*, transported from Earth in the early days of colonisation.

> I’ve been asked if Radchaai “tea” is really tea, or if it’s perhaps just a convenient term for some sort of Space Caffeine. In fact, **it’s tea. As in made from the leaves of Camellia sinensis.**

The 'fancy' tea (*"Daughter of Fishes"*) is evidently some kind of high-quality [oolong tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oolong).

> There’s a named tea in Ancillary Sword: it’s called Daughter of
> Fishes, and best I can tell you is, it’s something like a really good
> oolong. So try some Ti Kuan Yin.

Breq typically drinks [green tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_tea).

> But what, you might be asking, is Breq’s everyday cuppa? Probably some sort of green tea, actually.